# Does algebraic base field extension preserve injective modules over noetherian rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, injective-module

It is well-know that flat base change in general does not preserve injective modules, i.e. let $M$ be an injective $R$-module and $R\to S$ be a flat morphism, then it is not necessary that $M\otimes_R S$ is an injective $S$-module.

Now let's consider a more special case:

> Let $R$ be a commutative noetherian algebra over a base field $k$ and $l/k$ be a (non-finite) algebraic field extension. Let $M$ be an injective $R$-module. Then is it necessary that $M\otimes_kl$ is an injective $R\otimes_kl$-module?

Notice that the answer is negative if $l/k$ is not algebraic as pointed out by @EricWofsey in the answer of [this stack exchange question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2294317/does-base-field-extension-preserve-injective-modules-over-noetherian-rings/2294359?noredirect=1#comment4721852_2294359).

Comment: Since $R$ is noetherian one can replace $M$ by $E(R/p)$, the injective hull of $R/p$ with $p$ prime ideal. Then we may assume $p=(0)$, and thus $R$ is an integral domain and $M=Q(R)$ is its field of fractions. Now the injective dimension of the extended module equals the injective dimension of the ring $Q(R)\otimes_kl$; see Fossum, *The structure of indecomposable injective modules*, Theorem I.1.

Comment: The question reduces to show that the tensor product of two field extensions, one algebraic, is self-injective. (I've found a paper of Menal showing the converse, but the result we are looking for isn't mentioned.)

Comment: At present I think I can prove this for $R$ a finitely generated $k$-algebra. This has the advantage that $Q(R)/k$ is a finitely generated field extension. Then split it into a pure transcendental and an algebraic (actually finite) one. The main issue is when the field extension $Q(R)/k$ is finite, the transcendental case being rather easy.